# Forcing TensorFlow-GPU to use the CPU from the command line

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have TensorFlow-GPU 1.0.0 installed on a server running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64.

I know I can use [`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42382106/395857) to hide one or several GPUs. Sometimes, I would like to hide all GPUs so that the TensorFlow-based program only uses the CPU. As a result, I tried

```
username@server:/scratch/coding/src$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python my_script.py
```

but this gives me the error message:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:509] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
```

Here is the `ConfigProto` I use:

```
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
      device_count={'CPU': 1, 'GPU': 1},
      allow_soft_placement=True, 
      log_device_placement=False
      )
sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
```

I know I could use `device_count={'GPU': 0}` to prevent the TensorFlow-based program from using the GPU, but I wonder whether this can be achieved from the command line when launching the program (without changing the `ConfigProto`).

The option `allow_soft_placement=True`, according to the documentation, is supposed to have TensorFlow  automatically choose an existing and supported device to run the operations in case the specified one doesn't exist.

My first reaction when I saw the message was that CUDA needs at least one GPU to successfully load but I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42287754/395857) that one can install GPU drivers and use TensorFlow-GPU on a machine even if the machine doesn't have GPU.

---

Here is the  `my_script.py` script I use for the test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(1, name = 'a')
b = tf.constant(3, name = 'b')
c = tf.constant(9, name = 'c')
d = tf.add(a, b, name='d')
e = tf.add(d, c, name='e')

session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
          device_count={'CPU': 1, 'GPU': 1},
          allow_soft_placement=True,
          log_device_placement=False
          )
sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
print(sess.run([d, e]))
```

Comment: I think that's really a warning than an error message, I see it all the time and things work

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov thanks good to know.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov By the way you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer: Stack Exchange questions with 0 upvote and 0 answer may be automatically deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "E" should've been a "W" or "I", that's just an informational message and should not affect functioning of your program