# How can I change which GPU (s) a TensorFlow program may use while the TensorFlow program is running?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

One can use the environment variable [`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42382106/395857) to specify which GPU (s) may TensorFlow use before the TensorFlow program starts, e.g. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python my_script.py`.

How can I change which GPU (s) a TensorFlow program may use while it is running?

I know that one could change the program to have checkpoints and rerun the TensorFlow program from these checkpoints with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` specifying which GPUs to use, but I wonder if there is some way to avoid relying on the program having checkpoints.

Comment: You can place portions of the computation graph on different GPUs by specifying the device when you define the ops

Comment: @kmario23 Thanks, I see, but you can't change that while the TensorFlow program is running, correct?

Comment: Oh, you meant to hop between GPU(s) while the program is in execution? That's tricky. A naive idea could be to use some control flow to redirect the execution to the desired GPU. It'd be interesting to see, though I haven't tried those yet..

Answer (score 1):

Consider using eager execution. It is perfectly tailored for this kind of dynamic tempering with your network.

```
import random
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = tf.constant(1)

for _ in range(10):
  dev = random.choice(['/cpu:0', '/gpu:0'])
  with tf.device(dev):
    x = x + 1
    print('res {} computed on {}'.format(x.numpy(), x.device))
```